# Bash, run script on every .jpg file in a directory with subdirectories

Tags: bash, unix

I have some working code, it's very simple - it copies every *.jpg file, renames it into *1.jpg, no worries.

```
for i in *.jpg; do cp $i ${i%%.jpg}1.jpg;  done
```

how can I run this, so that it works on every file in a directory, every file in the subdirectories of that directory

example directory structure:

```
    test/test1/test2/somefile.jpg
    test/anotherfile.jpg
    test/test1/file.jpg
etc
```

Comment: 'every file in the subdirectories of that directory' = recursively

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The command to do anything recursively to a directory structure is `find`:

```
find . -name "*.jpg" -exec bash -c 'file="{}"; cp "$file" "${file%%.jpg}1.jpg"' \;
```

Using `-exec` instead of `for i in $(find ...)` will handle filenames that contain a space. Of course, there is still one quoting gotcha; if the filename contains a `"`, the `file="{}"` will expand to `file="name containing "quote characters""`, which is obviously broken (`file` will become `name containing quote` and it will try to execute the `characters` command).

If you have such filenames, or you might, then print out each filename separated with null characters (which are not allowed in filenames) using `-print0`, and use `while read -d $'\0' i` to loop over the null-delimited results:

```
find . -name "*.jpg" -print0 | \
    (while read -d $'\0' i; do cp "$i" "${i%%.jpg}1.jpg";  done)
```

As with any complex command like this, it's a good idea to test it without executing anything to make sure it's expanding to something sensible before running it. The best way to do this is to prepend the actual command with `echo`, so instead of running it, you will see the commands that it will run:

```
find . -name "*.jpg" -print0 | \
    (while read -d $'\0' i; do echo cp "$i" "${i%%.jpg}1.jpg";  done)
```

Once you've eyeballed it and the results looks good, remove the `echo` and run it again to run it for real.

Comment: find . -name "*.jpg" -exec bash -c 'file="{}"; cp "$file" "${file%%.jpg}1.jpg"' \;

is the correct script, thanks very much

Answer (score 2):

If you have Bash 4, you can use `globstar` to enable recursive filename expansion (i.e. matches files in subdirectories as well)

```
shopt -s globstar
for i in **/*.jpg; do cp "$i" "${i%%.jpg}1.jpg";  done
```

p/s: I added quotes around the arguments for `cp` in case there are spaces in filenames or whatnot.