# Linux copying subdirectories with same name to a file

Tags: linux, bash

Imagine a directory structure that looks like :

```
/a1/b1/c1/O

/a1/b2/c2/O

/a1/b3/c3/O
```

how do I copy all content of the "O" directory to one file?

I've tried `cp -r /a1/*/O ~/O` and it fails

Comment: Have you tried `cp -r /a1/*/O/ ~/O`

Comment: @coin Yes, the result is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One more glob pattern needed. Use:

```
cp -r /a1/*/O/* ~/O
```

OR to make this command work for any depth use `find`:

```
find /a1 -type d -name 'O' -print0 | xargs -0 -I % cp -r %/* ~/O
```

Comment: +1, can you modify it to be insensitive to the depth of the directory? For example, it should work for /a1/b1/c1/d1/O and /a5/b5/c5/d5/e5/f5/g5/h5/O

Comment: Now that you mention about that, I found something similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13236344/linux-command-output-as-a-parameter-of-another-command

Comment: Shouldn't the first command be `cp -r /a1/*/*/O/* ~/O` since the question says `O/` is 2 levels inside a1, not 1.

Comment: Yes that's correct, but I guess due to variable depth OP found `find` more suitable.