# Process sed-(stream editor)-output further

Tags: bash, sed, piping

I'm a **bash**-scripting newbie and don't even know how to formulate my question. I've skimmed [this tutorial](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-0), but couldn't find an appropriate code example. This is what I want...

I have a list of *hostnames*, (*hostname* being *google.com* and such), which looks like:

```
1,hostname_1
2,hostname_2
...
n,hostname_n
```

I want to remove the number in the front, that can be easily done with:

```
originList="originList.txt"
preparedList="preparedList.txt"
ipv6list="ipv6list.txt"

sed 's/[0-9]*,//' <$originList >$preparedList
```

But instead of piping the output to `preparedList.txt` I'd like to use it in my **dig** command:

```
sed 's/[0-9]*,//' <$originList | dig **HERE** AAAA +short >> $ipv6List
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linux command output as a parameter of another command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13236344/linux-command-output-as-a-parameter-of-another-command)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this:

```
sed -e 's/^[[:digit:]]*,//' FILE  | xargs -I {} dig {}  AAAA +short
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **cut** & GNU **parallel**:

```
cut -d',' -f2 hostnames  | parallel 'dig {}  AAAA +short'
```