# Use output of a command for another

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line

In my local machine my executable is stored at

```
.stack-work/install/x86_64-osx/lts-13.0/8.6.3/bin/nonosolver-exe
```

In my cloud instance it is stored at

```
./.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux-tinfo6/lts-13.0/8.6.3/bin/nonosolver-exe
```

Thus the executable will always be in `./.stack-work/install/{??}/nonosolver-exe`, depending on the machine and version of GHC im using. So in my make file I'm using

```
find ./.stack-work/install -name nonosolver-exe
```

to find my executable.

---

How do I take the result of `find` to start a daemon with `setsid` (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19233529/run-bash-script-as-daemon#_=_)):

```
setsid {path to executable} >/dev/null 2>&1 < /dev/null &
```

I have tried (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13236344/linux-command-output-as-a-parameter-of-another-command)) :

```
find ./.stack-work/install -name nonosolver-exe -exec setsid {} >/dev/null 2>&1 < /dev/null &
```

to no avail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Shell**

Use `$(...)` to insert the stdout of one command into another as a string:

```
setsid "$(find ./.stack-work/install -name nonosolver-exe)" >/dev/null 2>&1 < /dev/null &
```

This will cause unexpected problems if you end up finding a number of matches other than one. You can store into a variable to do error checking first:

```
exe_path="$(find ./.stack-work/install -name nonosolver-exe)"
# check non-empty and no newlines
setsid "${exe_path}" >/dev/null 2>&1 < /dev/null &
```

**Makefile**

The makefile equivalent to the bash `$(...)` construct is `$(shell ...)`. And variables are expanded with `$(...)`, not `${...}`:

```
setsid "$(shell find ./.stack-work/install -name nonosolver-exe)" >/dev/null 2>&1 < /dev/null
```

Or

```
EXE_PATH = $(shell find ./.stack-work/install -name nonosolver-exe)
setsid "$(EXE_PATH)" >/dev/null 2>&1 < /dev/null
```

Comment: your solution works great on the command line, but when i put it into a makefile the "${..}" expression resolves to "". Any ideas?

Comment: Shell variables and make variables don't have quite the same syntax. I'll update

Comment: EXE_PATH works, the makefile output was `EXE_PATH=./.stackwork/.../nonosolver-exe`, but the process didn't start. I then tested with `echo "$(EXE_PATH)"` and its showing `echo ""` so i'm guessing `setsid` didn't get to EXE_PATH either.

Comment: I used `setsid "$(shell find ./.stack-work/install -name nonosolver-exe)" >/dev/null 2>&1 < /dev/null &` and its working now, thank you

Comment: What about pipes? to xargs?

Comment: @BladeMight. What about them? Why start a third process when two will do?

Comment: Use them instead of $(...), just as an alternative.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I posted an answer using pipe & xargs.

Answer (score 2):

Using the pipe and xargs:

```
find ./.stack-work/install -name nonosolver-exe -print0 | xargs -0 -I{} setsid "{}" >/dev/null 2>&1 < /dev/null &
```

Comment: This would work equally well in a makefile as it does in the shell. Very +1